# unw_get_proc_name() sporadically returns UNW_EUNSPEC and UNW_ENOINFO errors

Tags: c++, linux, libunwind

I am using libunwind 1.4.0 to collect the stack-trace. It almost always works, but there are cases that I either get `unspecified (general) error` or `no unwind info found` when calling `unw_get_proc_name`. I can walk through the stack-trace in core-dumps (using gdb), and the same binary on the same machine runs without any issues the next time I run the program. Anyone experienced a similar issue and knows how to fix this?

Comment: I think all the incidents are happening on RHEL 6.2 and after the process catches a signal. I'm not sure if the presence of a signal is causing the issue, since I have not been able to reproduce the issue with the same signal on the same platform, but it sporadically happens when running automated tests.

Comment: Can you post stack trace log here or suspicious code snippet you think?